# Has anyone used yFiles library with Javafx, to visualize graphs?

Tags: java, javafx, yfiles

i would like to know if anyone did use *yFiles* library (*yWorks*) with Javafx, to manipulate (with algorithms, like shortest path...) and visualize (zoom, color node, color edges) graphs? 
i'm actually searching a good open source library to visualize complex graphs with Javafx.

thanks in advance for your answer.

Comment: [yFiles for JavaFX](http://www.yworks.com/products/yfiles-for-javafx) has been built exactly for this purpose. It's not open source. There aren't many high-quality JavaFX graph drawing solutions other than this commercial offering.

Comment: Yes i found this library too, but as you said it's not an open source. The problem is that i must use Javafx.
I also found JUNG library.

Answer (score 0):

I hope [Jgraphx](https://github.com/jgraph/jgraphx) (an open source library) might help

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But is JGraphX available for Javafx?

Comment: For Javafx, i think it is [not available](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27799718/equivalent-to-jgraph-for-javafx8) :( ... Also see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18372330/jgraph-in-javafx)